# What is the most performant way to make component state changeable from inside of a component as well as outside of it [VueJS]?

Tags: vue.js, performance, components

I have created an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-rain-v6zc5l?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue):

Code of internal component:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ internalVal }}</div>
  <button :style="{ marginTop: '32px' }" @click="() => onClick()">
    Increment inside component
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    externalVal: Number,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      internalVal: this.externalVal,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.internalVal++;
      this.$emit("change", this.internalVal);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    externalVal(newValue) {
      this.internalVal = newValue;
    },
  },
  emits: {},
};
</script>
```

Code of external component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <HelloWorld
      :externalVal="externalVal"
      @change="(val) => (externalVal = val)"
    />
  </div>
  <button @click="() => externalVal++" :style="{ marginTop: '16px' }">
    Increment outsidecomponent
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorldVue from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld: HelloWorldVue,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      externalVal: 0,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

It works as expected, so I can change counter value from inside of component as well as from outside. But I dislike this approach due to watcher existence, so if I will need to change not a counter, but an array of objects as a state, then I will need to use deep watch, which will make my app slower depends on the array length.

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior, but get a better performance?

Comment: Consider explaining your case further. How is it supposed to look like with an array? The mention of performance indicates this could be the case for premature optimization, as it won't be a bottleneck. Design-wise, I see no reason for internalVal to exist, it could be regular 2-way binding